# Comparing lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, reduce

I have to define a function called zeros which takes input of two lists and returns a boolean which returns True if the number 0 appears the same amount of times in each list and false otherwise.

This is the last question in my homework and and I have managed to solve the question get it to work but I wondered if anybody can spot ways in which to reduce the amount of code. Any ideas are appreciated.
My code so far is as follows:

```hs
x :: Int
x = 0 
instances::[Int]->Int
instances [] = 0
instances (y:ys)
    | x==y = 1+(instances ys)
    | otherwise = instances ys



zeros :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
zeros [] [] = False
zeros x y
       | ((instances x) == (instances y)) = True
       | otherwise = False
```

Comment: Seems to me that `zeros [] []` should equal `True`? At least it doesn't seem any more false than `zeros [1] []`, which your code would consider `True`. I'm not sure you even need to handle the case `zeros [] []`...

Comment: no i don't think it should be because if the lists were empty then they would contain no zeros at all hence it would be false

Comment: I'm having trouble convincing myself that "no zeros" and "zero zeros" aren't the same thing. For example, `zeros [1] []` would return `True` the way you have written things (both have zero zeros). Whereas `zeros [] []` would return `False` (despite that both have zero zeros).

Comment: A really short solution : `zeroes = (==) \`on\` filter (== 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without giving too much away, since this is homework, here are a few hints.

Do you know about list comprehensions yet? They would be useful in this case. For example, you could combine them with an `if` expression to do something like this:

```
*Main> let starS s = [if c == 's' then '*' else ' ' | c <- s]
*Main> starS "schooners"
"*       *"
```

You can even use them to do filtering. For example:

```
*Main> let findFives xs = [x | x <- xs, x == 5]
*Main> findFives [3,7,5,6,3,4,5,7,5,5]
[5,5,5,5]
```

Neither of these is a complete answer, but it shouldn't be hard to see how to adapt these structures to your situation.

You should also think about whether you actually need a guard here! For example, here's a function written with a guard in the same style as yours:

```
lensMatch [] [] = True
lensMatch xs ys
             | ((length xs) == (length ys)) = True
             | otherwise = False
```

Here's a function that does the same thing!

```
lensMatch' xs ys = length xs == length ys
```

You can see that they are the same; testing the first:

```
*Main> lensMatch [1..4] [1..4]
True
*Main> lensMatch [1..4] [1..5]
False
*Main> lensMatch [] [1..5]
False
*Main> lensMatch [] []
True
```

And testing the second:

```
*Main> lensMatch' [1..4] [1..4]
True
*Main> lensMatch' [1..4] [1..5]
False
*Main> lensMatch' [] [1..5]
False
*Main> lensMatch' [] []
True
```

Finally, I agree very strongly with sblom's comment above; `zeros [] []` should be `True`! Think about the following statement: "For each item x in set s, x > 0". If set s is empty, then the statement is true! It's true because there are no items in s at all. This seems to me like a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe nobody has suggested to use [`foldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr) yet.  Not the shortest or best definition, but IMO the most educational:

```
instances :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
instances n = foldr incrementIfEqual 0
    where incrementIfEqual x subtotal
              | x == n = subtotal + 1
              | otherwise = subtotal

zeros :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
zeros xs ys = instances 0 xs == instances 0 ys
```

Though for a really brief definition of `instances`, what I came up with is basically the same as Abizern:

```
instances :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
instances x = length . filter (==x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of doing this in one pass by filtering each list to get just the zeroes and then comparing the length of the lists to see if they are equal?

```
zeroCompare xs ys = cZeroes xs == cZeroes ys
  where
    cZeroes as = length $ filter (== 0) as
```

Comment: I did consider that and i actually think thats what my tutor will be looking for but i was unsure to implement the filter and guard in one sweep

Comment: what is the significance of 'as' ?

Comment: What's the significance of `xs` and `ys`? None. It's just a way of stating an input parameter. I could have written in it **points free style** as `cZeroes = length . filter (== 0)`, but I thought it would be easier for you to understand it with a parameter.

Comment: ah i actually understood it in a points free style. thanks a lot though dude!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `length` and `filter`, you can take the result of a predicate `p`, convert it to 0 or 1, and sum the result:

```
count p = sum . map (fromEnum.p)

--or

import Data.List
count p = foldl' (\x -> (x+).fromEnum.p) 0
```

In your case, `p` is of course `(==0)`. Converting `Bool` to `Int` using `fromEnum` is a very useful trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to deal with both list simultaneously, which is a little bit lengthy, but easy to understand:

```
zeros xs ys = cmp xs ys == 0 where
  cmp (0:xs) ys = cmp xs ys + 1
  cmp xs (0:ys) = cmp xs ys - 1
  cmp (_:xs) ys = cmp xs ys
  cmp xs (_:ys) = cmp xs ys
  cmp [] []     = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break the problem down into smaller problems involving helper functions.

This is how I would break it down:

1. Main function to compare two counts
2. Count helper function

First: You need a way to count the amount of zeroes in a list. For example, I would approach this by doing the following if searching for the number of 0 in an integer list:

```
count :: [Int] -> Int
count xs = foldl (\count num -> if num == 0 then (count + 1) else count) 0 xs
```

Second: You need a way to compare the count of two lists. Essentially, you need a function that takes two lists in as parameters, calculates the count of each list, and then returns a boolean depending on the result. For example, if each list is an int list, corresponding with my count example above:

```
    equalZeroes :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
    equalZeroes x y = (count x) == (count y)
```

You could also define count under the where keyword inside the equalZeroes function like so:

```
equalZeroes :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
equalZeroes x y = (count x) == (count y)
    where
        count :: [Int] -> Int
        count xs = foldl (\count num -> if num == 0 then (count + 1) else count) 0 xs
```

When running this code, calling the function as so would get the desired boolean values returned:

```
equalZeroes [0,1,4,5,6] [1,4,5,0,0]
-> False

 equalZeroes [0,1,4,5,6] [1,4,5,0]
 -> True
```